# 2D arrays in MQL4 not functioning as expected

Tags: multidimensional-array, multi-index, mql4

I want to create a two-dimensional array with variable number of rows and columns. Of course, the number of rows and columns is determined at the beginning of the execution of the expert. A part of the code I wrote is as follows and an error was generated like this.

'[' - invalid index value   Ae_1320_test.mq4    85  13

Note: It should be noted that column 13 in row 85 refers to the second index of matrix A. A[](column 13:[)]

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                         test.mq4 |
//|                        Copyright 2021, MetaQuotes Software Corp. |
//|                                             https://www.mql5.com |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Copyright 2023, MetaQuotes Software Corp."
#property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
#property version   "1.00"
#property strict

extern int  m=30; 
extern int  n=5;

int      Base_Idx[];

double   pt, b[], A[][], PivotColumn[];

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
{
//---
   pt = Point;
   if (Digits == 3 || Digits == 5)
   {
      pt*=10;
   }     
//---
return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
{
//---

//---
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
{
   for(int i=0; m-1; i++) for(int j=0; n;j++) A[i][j]=0;

//-------------- Matrix A ---------------------- 
   for (int i=0;m-1;i++)
   {
      A[i][0]=i+2;
      A[i][1]=i+4;
      A[i][2]=i+6;
      A[i][3]=i+8;
      A[i][4]=i+10;
      b[i]=Close[i+1];
   }

   double tab[][];
   for(int i=0; m;   i++) for(int j=0; 2*m+n;   j++) tab[i][j]=0;
   for(int i=0; m-1; i++) for(int j=0; 2*m+n-1; j++) tab[i][j]=A[i][j];
   for(int i=0; m-1; i++) tab[i][2*m+n]=b[i];
   for(int j=0;2*m+n-1; j++) tab[m][j]=2;

//+----------------------- Phase One Of SIMPLEX Method ----------------------------+
   for(int i=0; m-1; i++) for(int j=0; 2*m+n; j++) tab[m][j]=tab[m][j]-tab[i][j];
return;
}
```

Comment: You need to show your full code. What you have shown is not enough to allow anyone to understand where your problems are occurring.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention. I edited my post and copied the full code into the post.

Comment: I've just scanned over your code and can see immediate problems. In your `for` statements, the second object should define the limit of the loop but it doesn't, it's just a calculation using `m` variable, you need to correct this straight away.